# Mac OS X (Lion) Safari: shortcut to focus on search input

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, safari, osx-lion

Whenever I need to search in Safari, I have to focus on the search bar with the mouse and then type, which I find inconvenient.

What is the shortcut for Mac OS X (Lion) Safari to focus on the search input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortcut to access the search box is <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

You can also focus the address bar with <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: It's the same shortcut as e.g. Mail's toolbar search box. `Cmd-F` is different functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not satisfied with a three-button shortcut and prefer something else, open **System Preferences**, select **Keyboard**, select **Keyboard Shortcuts** tab and in **Application Shortcuts** create a new shortcut:

- Menu title is **Google Search…** (not three dots but an ellipsis, press <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> to get one of those)
- Application is **Safari**.
- Keyboard shortcut is up to you but I prefer <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

Close the preferences and enjoy your new shortcut.

Comment: Yes I'd prefer ⌘ + K too just like in Chrome and Firefox. Thank you!